# Working with PIC to send data to server

Tags: pic, microprocessor, tcp-ip, network-interface

I'm currently working with the flyport from OpenPicus, it has 24FJ256GA106 PIC processor in it and I was looking for the best way to send information from the flyport to a server.

I want to know how can I send this data? In a packet form to the server? Does anyone know where I can find information on accomplishing this?

I already have previous experience with .Net programming and was hoping to have it pushed to a SQL server. However, getting the data sent would be enough information to get me started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the device already has the Microchip TCP/IP stack compiled up and running so it shouldn't be too hard to implement a HTTP client that POSTs the data to your web server. I think there is at least one example HTTP client with their distribution. If not, there are other implementations available. See Dangerous Prototype's [web platform](http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/Web_Platform), they have a similar chip with a TCP/IP stack.

Making a .NET web application should be quite easy if you've done it before and from there it's also easy to insert the data into an SQL database.

Answer (score 4):

I've worked a lot with the Microchip TCP/IP Stack and I've found in most cases it's easier to have your server connect to the PIC and request data rather than have the PIC post the data to the server.

Comment: I've considered this as a possible alternative, my only issue with requesting data from the PIC is that I want it to have the ability to be easily accessible if on the other side of a router and this becomes problematic because then I would need port forwarding.

Comment: While I haven't tried implementing a generic TCP client if you review the Microchip TCP/IP stack help file under TCP you can see the API that would need to be used to implement a TCP client.